# Run Javascript Jquery function on two different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i have those classes:

```
.slider
.sliderlogo
```

and i have those pieces of codes:

```
var sc=$(".slider img").size();
$(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);
$(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
```

what's the right way to add the other "slidelogo" class to the JS so it will run on the other class as well?

generaly its like:

```
(".slider #1,.sliderlogo #1")
```

bit its not working for the above code lines.
thanks in advance.

Comment: ID must be unique in the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have issues with your markup, as IDs must be unique on the document and cannot begin with a number. If you must use the Ids, try building them as something like `'slider' + count` and `'sliderLogo' + count`. so that each is unique.

Comment: yeah i forgot that i numbered 2 groups of images in the same id's.
however,ID's can start with numbers, since HTML5 arrived.

Comment: @NetanelDadon Technically that is true, but as with all HTML5 features, you should be aware of them in case you have to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` should be unique in the entire document, so i recommend you to use classes instead, something like `.item-1, .item-2` and then change the code to:

```
var sc=$(".slider img").size();
var selector = ".slider .item-" + count + ", .sliderlogo .item-" + count;
$(selector).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);
$(selector).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
```

Answer (score 1):

As David says, the id must be unique, so try changing them to

```
.slider #slider1
```

and

```
.sliderlogo #sliderlogo1
```

etc.

then use:

```
(".slider #slider"+count+",.sliderlogo #sliderlogo"+count)
```